# Would mission command, squad tactics etc. make sense in an ancient or medieval setting?

Tags: warfare

In my setting I want my isolationist, low-manpower city state or duchy to turn the tables on an invading empire --which employs rigid/ritualistic tactics similar in spirit to the phalanx-- through overwhelmingly superior military organization.

Now any drastic changes to massed cavalry and infantry lining up and smashing at each other took the horrifying combination of highly advanced firearms and a world war fought with traditional tactics.  That being said I do not see firearms as the block here.

Training and communication seem like bigger issues to maintain cohesion as opposed to just lining people up and telling them to march in a direction. Which are also solvable in such a setting without hand-waving.

So is there anything I am failing to consider?

Comment: The phalanx was a superior tactical structure in its day. The manipular legion (organized in 20 two-century maniples) was superior to the phalanx; a maniple was "a phalanx with joints". The Marian (or cohortal) legion (organized in ten six-century cohorts) was superior to the manipular legion. See the WP article on the [Structural history of the Roman army](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_history_of_the_Roman_military) for an introduction. A good Roman tactician, e.g., Caesar or Belisarius, most definitely did not just line people up and tell them to march forward.

Comment: And yes, the Roman army did use effective training to instill unit cohesion and really had an effective communications system on the battlefield. See [cornicen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornicen) for example. See [Roman infantry tactics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_infantry_tactics) for a brief overview. What happened in the western European Middle Ages resulted from the extreme lack of resources and men; when states grew richer and more populous they re-introduced effective battlefield tactics, which had never been forgotten.

Comment: Phalanx vs. Roman manipular legion is a good example. Also consider heavy cavalry and armored infantry vs. massed archers protected by terrain and sharpened stakes as at Agincourt.

Comment: Thank you for the examples. I was going on bit of a hyperbole since my comparison is with modern tactics, otherwise I am aware command structures and organizational nuances were still there and not wildly different from each other or today, like the breakdown of Central Asian tumens. That being said tactics employed were still rule-based and both specialization and one can argue also the battlefield initiative was at the 100 men unit level minimum and anything more granular was arguably all choreographed

Comment: 100-man units *did not* have initiatives. Don't forget limitations of communications technology. In a world where the general in command can broadcast signals (by bugle sounds, for example) but there is no effective way for the commander of a small-ish subunits to send signals up the chain of command, having a centurion take the initiative and do something unexpected was a sure way to bring chaos and disorganization. That's why major initiatives were reserved to commanders of major sections of the army, who actually had couriers who could keep the commander-in-chief informed.

Comment: That is exactly what I am saying. Best case the century had the same initiative a single individual in a squad would have today keeping formation with everyone else etc. What I am asking is how do I make a squad or even individual be able to have that initiative without radios, with training compensating for the lack of instant communications to some degree.

Comment: This is something of a frame challenge, but might a steppe tribe match your story better? Whilst nomadic, this enabled them to make far more heavy use of horse archer skirmishing, something that the Phylanx specifically is weak to. This combined with the ability conduct a highly mobile war as territory was less of an issue and a much smaller force where everyone is well practised hunting with each other, might be more conductive to the tactics you describe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The place to look would be the Prussian reform movement of the late Napoleonic wars. This is one of the few armies in history to manage anything close to what you are asking for. What this suggests is that you have three primary problems in your setting:

### Economics

Why did no one in northern Europe field Phalanxes? Or why was Rome able to adopt the maniple? For these two questions, the answer is economics. These tactical developments required time to train in. This time could not be spent farming, so required agricultural surplices over substance farming that northern Europe could not provide. So you will need to answer the question of where the food and equipment comes from, for a significant proportion of your population to spend there entire lives learning, training and preparing for war, in addition to spending there entire professional lives as soldiers. This was a big constraint in armys up until the renaissance. Rome is one of the few known large states to have a professional army prior to the renaissance. Your Phylanx using invading empire can afford to have its troops at home in the key periods of spring and autumn to farm. Only coming out to campaign in the summer when the crops are growing.

Note that going from Phylanx level to the level of initiative you are talking about is something that will take decades due to the need to first educate enough people to do the training, and then train all of your soldiers from what is effectively primary level education.

### Culture

The next problem is culture. Initiative in an organization interacts directly with the culture of authority and rewards. Do people expect there leaders to consult them and listen to their ideas, or do they expect to by punished for speaking out of place? You need a state where the individuals involved feel engaged in the goal of the campaign. Since your setting is an invasion, patriotism should help here. However, they can't be motivated purely by patriotism, as this would not explain how the army would have fostered initiative prior to the invasion, as this is not something that is easy to introduce. As for rewards, you need a society with a minimal level of meritocracy so that the people given these lower ranked positions actually are competent enough to run a squad and want to take risks so they can advance. Finally you need enough education that you have a large enough pool of competent people to command such positions. Most classical cultures didn't educate enough people to provide such a pool.

### Weapons

In order for initiative to be useful, you need a way to translate that initiative into damage. This means that you smallest unit of combat must be capable of performing enough damage to overcome an opponent groups defense. This means something ranged like a bow or gun. Its only really in the late 19th into 20th century that guns become accurate enough and have high enough rates of fire for a group split into squads to perform enough morale damage to break a groups charge.

Comment: Thank you for the well thought answer! Maybe a relatively small military caste would explain how the cultural and economic background came to be. As for the weaponry, how about slings with lead bullets?

Comment: @VictorS It depends on how large your opponents forces are and how you structure the caste. Ultimately a small military caste is what early medieval knights where.

Comment: As for slings, they don't provide enough damage to pose a serious threat to a tortoise. You'd have to be getting into serious asymmetric warfare for that to pose a real threat, which comes down to the structure of the supply chains. Does the attacking force have a significant supply chain or are they foraging? Does the attacking force have any qualms about slaughtering entire villages because they might be harboring a squad of their opposition? Military's and their doctrine are shaped by their socieoeconomic context as much as any technology.

Comment: In other words, if I have so much surplus to spend on a squad of your slingers, why not spend that on a single armored knight, who is effective on land defence as well as asymmetric warfare?

Comment: If your world doesn't have the stirrup, then that helps constrain the development of heavy cavalry, but that forces you into something more like months of hit and run slinging by small raiding parties, rather than an actual battle. If the opponent is sufficiently brutal about dealing with hiding places then there isn't much in the way of options.

Comment: Hmm as far as I know shepherd's slings were pretty nasty in battle and the main reason they fell out of use is the time consuming training, difficulty of use etc.

Comment: The key thing to remember is we aren't talking about individual deaths. A shepherds sling is only going to get 10-20 shots of before the squad is overrun. Allowing for inaccuracy, thats at most one to two people rendered combat ineffective. Thats trading an entire squad for one or two casulties at most. Not a good trade when the phalanx is much easier to reinforce.

Comment: Shepherds slings where effective on an classical battlefield, when in mass and supporting a melee force which could protect the slingers from being overrun by the opponents. In a small squad, you can't provide that melee protection. Its only really with the introduction of cartridge rifles that a squad of 10 could kill more than its own numbers before being overrun.

Answer (score 6):

Ancient armies were not *stupid*. Their tactics balance their goals, their constraints, their information available, and their resources available...just like ours do today.

Medieval tactics were generally built around horses as the kings of the battlefield. Infantry formations were designed to protect from fast-moving cavalry attacks (pikemen, for example). When horses and archers were superseded by more-deadly artillery and machine guns and tanks, the infantry formations changed from massed formations to dispersed formations.

It's a wonderful thought that a small unit could peel off a larger formation to take advantage of some weakness, but it rarely worked in practice: Small infantry units would be hacked apart by much-faster cavalry, decimated by arrows, and finally rolled-over by a larger infantry formation. Mass was not *power* - mass was *survivability*. Mass and maneuver together were power.

You can fight a medieval battle based on *mobility* and *surprise* and *economy of force* over the more common *mass* (look up [Jomini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine-Henri_Jomini) for the *principles of war*). Usually this means sowing confusion among the enemy, using deception to mislead the enemy generals, and using a shorter *decision cycle* than the enemy in order to act/react faster than they can. However, that kind of fight requires greater training and preparation...and one of the key constraints of most combatants is the cost of those preparations.

Historically, if you can afford to pay a smaller force to train for months, then you can also afford to pay a much larger less-trained force. Recall that the biggest killer in medieval wars was disease, not combat. Also surprise can be very hard to achieve, especially if enemy spies see your army training. The smaller force tends to have less capacity to absorb the unexpected. So it's not surprising that many leaders chose to go for *mass* over more complex strategies. *Simplicity* in an era of slow and unreliable communications can also be a big advantage.

Generally, most of medieval Europe was too impoverished and squalid to be worth the monumental cost of a Big-Empire campaign of invasion and conquest. Instead, think about small campaigns to influence succession, or to force a neighbor to part with a barony or two. Different combatants, whether ancient or modern, may have different *political goals* for the conflict...and while both may want to extend their *influence*, that influence might not involve conquest at all. If that's confusing, then you just haven't read enough Shakespeare.

Comment: No one is saying they were. As for spending all that effort instead of going and getting a large mercenary contingent, I thought about it but I want an isolationist, low manpower military that does not let the enemy advance much e.g. not your usual guerillas

Comment: @VictorS that looks like information the belongs in your question above. Seems like you might have a mismatch in goals, though. If so, one side will be in for an unpleasant surprise.

Comment: Yeah might be a good idea to be more explicit about that. What do you mean by mismatch in goals?

Comment: @VictorS added a paragraph on goals.

Comment: I see your point, although I think you are limiting your perspective a bit too much to Western Europe. You also need to consider warfare with the rise of Islam, especially with battles like Yarmouk or Manzikert, where pretty much the opposite of what you described in the last two paragraphs was regularly the case.

Comment: @VictorS The answer is focused upon Europe because the title used the term *medieval*. Had the question used a different term (Song Dynasty, Byzantine, Mughal, etc), the answer would be focused differently.

Comment: I think arguing semantics will take us off tangent here, but I have to point out Umayyads and the Byzantine empire both belong to the Medieval Europe, especially considering the former making it as far as invading Gaul while the latter was, well, the Roman Empire

Answer (score 4):

The situation with the ancient Greek Phalanx is ore complicated than the OP seems to think. the Phalanx isn't "just" a tactical formation, but also encapsulates the social order of Classical Greece as well. One might wonder why the Greeks evolved such a formation given the argumentative and relatively individualistic (for the time) culture of classical Greece.

Members of the Phalanx were mostly middle class farmers, with some townspeople and tradesmen thrown into the mix. The arms and equipment were about equivalent to buying a new car in Purchasing Power Parity terms, firmly excluding the poor, while horses were rare and far more expensive in ancient Greece, so the domain of the aristocracy. A wall of fully equipped farmers with bronze helmets, 3' diameter shields locked together and protected by bronze breastplates, greaves and other metal armour was essentially immune to the weapons that the poor could bring to battle (stones, javelins etc.) as well as the thrown javelins of the aristocratic cavalry (stirrup mounted shock cavalry was 1000 years in the future).

Standing together as equals on the battlefield and unable to be defeated or driven off by the rich *or* the poor, Greek farmers could also stand together as equals in the Agora and eventually in the *Ekklasia* to create and enforce the rules and laws of their communities.

The Classical Phalanx was also able to co-opt the poor and aristocrats as part of the formation; for example cavalry tended to operate to protect the flanks, while "Peltasts" drawn from the ranks of the poor attempted to harry the flanks or disorganize the enemy Phalanx when it was on the move, and thus more vulnerable to being crushed by an organized advance by the opposing Phalanx.

[image]

*Peltast*

The Phalanx was also capable of some limited tactical manouevre, although only the Spartans, who drilled full time, were capable of really exploiting the possibilities of a Phalanx. The Theban *Boeotarch* [Epaminondas](http://://www.ancient.eu/Epaminondas/) also introduced very innovative tactics that turned the traditional Phalanx from a solid line of troops arrayed 8 deep into an articulated formation, defeating the Spartans using these tactics at the [Battle of Leuctra](https://www.ancient.eu/Battle_of_Leuctra/) (371 BC), and then invading Laconia and overthrowing Spartan rule there as well, before dying at the [Battle of Mantinea](https://www.ancientgreecereloaded.com/files/ancient_greece_reloaded_website/wars_and_battles/battle_of_mantinea.php#battle2) (362 BC).

"Special Forces" also existed in various Greek polities during the period. The Spartans had a 300 man elite corps who served as the King's guard and stood at the right of the line to anchor the Spartan Phalanx and prevent it from drifting to the right, while the Thebans created the "Sacred Band", a 300 man strong striking force made of paired homosexual lovers. The Sacred Band detached itself from the main body of the Theban force during the Battle of Leuctra and struck the Spartan flank, preventing them from carrying out some sort of countermarch or manouevre while the main body of the Thebans bore down on them.

In terms of the concept of "Mission Command", independent commanders generally could only receive general instructions from their Ekklasia, and the various elements of a Greek Army would be unable to communicate with each other during the encounter, so the local *Stratigoi* would need to be able to assess the situation and take whatever action they felt was appropriate. The charge of the "Sacred Band", for example, is said to have been triggered by [Pelopidas](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Pelopidas) observing the Spartans beginning to countermarch, rather than any sort of command given by Epaminondas during the actual battle.

So although the idea of "Mission Command" may not have been formalized in the manner we think of it today, the basic elements of the concept did exist.

Comment: Exactly, the organizational structure of any significant military is a reflection of the social context it draws from. This is as much about shaping the society of the city state as it is the military. [Conways law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_law) seems appropriate here.

Comment: See this is where I am coming form - the Spartan prestige guard was part of the ritualistic 'choreography' that did not really make much tactical sense, which led to their biggest defeat in Leuctra. What Thebans did there is part of my inspiration actually but I want to make it more systematic - as squads engage the enemy host they observe the right wing dominating the movement, so they set and execute different objectives at squad level like trying to split off and destroy vulnerable sections of the phalanx left-to-right, keeping the pressure on the command wing etc.

Answer (score 4):

The constraints as written...are not the best so forgive me for taking the liberties of adding some variables since I think everyone else has done plenty on highlighting the strengths of something employing a phalanx as a conquering method and the use of cavalry and ranged units against it.

First of all I shall point out the latter two are very effective due to the fact the phalanx is fundamentally weak to having to pivot so a highly mobile enemy is one it isn't good against and the advantage of hitting a foe beyond their range is something i dont think requires elaboration.

Economics has come up a bit, and I'll just add a small note: conquest is expensive, and to use Rome the classic example as the...classic example there were quite literally entire periods where the economy of the nation existed solely to fuel the military conquest of other lands in hopes of an influx of the local populaces riches...maintaining an army is expensive - especially at great distance and/or inconvenient terrain. This is important because a small low-manpower state like you mentioned is highly unlikely to be a good target which would make the invasion very unpopular...history shows expensive and unpopular decisions typically leads to governments being overthrown.

This in turn means that while a well organized guerilla style engagement can bog down the invasion and "win" by using terrain for ambushes and even potentially "calculated" disasters like a manufactured landslide or dam break in very niche situations (low manpower really ties hands here), or even doing things like intentionally leaving things like fine wines and foods after "evacuating" that have been poisoned to ruin command structure...and appear to win. The ultimate victory will probably be because the empire decides the gains do not justify expense or the current emperor is deposed entirely.

However to not entirely toss the notion of our brave underdog to the wind...there is one other option and that would require us to take some inspiration from the Russians...you let a harsh winter wipe out the enemy and you harass the army just enough that it can't flee properly...Operation Uranus if you want a name. Essentially, your small army baits the enemy deep into their turf for a nasty winter to make a long march back, sends the bulk of the for around to encircle and harry them the entire walk back so they die cold, hungry and tired assuming your regular raids and attacks to keep the miserable the whole trip doesnt kill the individual first...but even this will be a very ugly "victory" for your underdog.

Answer (score 1):

FRAME CHALLENGE:

I think your basic idea is flawed because since your invading military force employing a phalanx or similar formation is demonstrating the highest level, for that period of time, of military organization.

Their soldiers will need to be trained very well trained so they can recognize the trumpets, flags, shouted orders that tell the formation to start moving, stop moving, wheel left or right or rotate right or left.  Also, the soldiers need to be trained to act properly in combat so the formation maintains its integrity during combat.

Your defenders can defeat the invaders through superior use of terrain and logistics and possessing greater es spirit de corps (commitment, resilience, and aggression).

If your invading army was less sophisticated and doesn't use phalanx-like formations then your question would be more consistent.  For instance, their forces lined up in a battle line in groups by function -- archers, slingers, cavalry and infantry -- and then attack as groups and not in combined simultaneous attacks.

Comment: I am imagining they would be trained to maintain a very high degree of battlefield awareness and tactical skills as opposed to what you described. So even some advanced formation like a phalanx or maniple would find themselves basically fighting a swarm of bees

Answer (score 1):

Communication technology is important.  Modern tactics presuppose that radios are cheap, light and reliable.  You can disperse a hundred small squads over some rough terrain and have them all keep in regular contact with headquarters, which may also be receiving reports from aerial or satellite surveillance.

If rapid communication means blowing horns, and detailed communication means sending runners, you can't coordinate a force like that.  Not only do you get chaos, but each squad will *feel* alone and lose morale.

Comment: Communication is probably less important to independent initiative than culture. The prussians managed independent brigades with no radios. The French failed to manage initiative in the 30s despite the availability of radios.